# Regex Replace is not Working after adding another Variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace text in a div with the variable `tagName`. I had it working before but I added something and it stopped working. There is nothing wrong with the code so far as the console shows. Here is my replace function (`tagName` is the word in the replace that we are trying to get back to, and `Color` is the background-color given by a button).

```
function removeMark (tagName, Color) {
var tagNameC = tagName.toUpperCase();
var IndAry = tags.indexOf(tagNameC);
tags.splice(IndAry, 1);
var Notes = document.getElementById("NoteHolder").innerHTML;
var MarkBack = new RegExp("(\\b + tagName + \\b)", "gim");
var ColorT = '"' + Color + '"';
var MarkBackTo = "<mark class='" + ColorT + "'>" + MarkBack + "</mark>"
var AfterRep = Notes.replace(MarkBackTo, "$1");
document.getElementById("NoteHolder").innerHTML = AfterRep;
var list = document.getElementById("myList");
var idmarker = "MarkID" + tagName;
var ElementID = document.getElementById(idmarker);
MarkList.removeChild(ElementID);
}
```

An example of what I am trying to replace is `<mark class="YelBoxCol">Test</mark>` and I am trying to get it back to `Test` (test is `tagName`) Before I added the class to mark it worked perfectly but now it wont remove the mark!

Answer (score 1):

I have a doubt in this code here. lets assume `Color = 'YelBoxCol';` --> string variable

```
var ColorT = '"' + Color + '"';
// output is "YelBoxCol"; --> string variable but with double quotes in the string as well so something like '"YelBoxCol"'
var MarkBackTo = "<mark class='" + ColorT + "'>" + MarkBack + "</mark>"
//output "<mark class='"YelBoxCol"'>yourRegex</mark>" --> you can see the double quotes in your class name.
```

That is the reason that your regex is breaking as it is not able to find the element with the class name `"YelBoxCol"` but there is a class name `YelBoxCol` , Not the difference in the quotes.

So change your code `var ColorT = '"' + Color + '"';` To

```
var ColorT = Color;
```

OR

change the code `var MarkBackTo = "<mark class='" + ColorT + "'>" + MarkBack + "</mark>"` to

```
var MarkBackTo = "<mark class=" + ColorT + ">" + MarkBack + "</mark>"
```

If this doesn't solve the problem then I sugget you to debug the code line by line, inspect the values in it and I am sure you will find out the issue, it is something small nothing major problem is seen in your code.

Comment: I might have spotted the problem. Could it be because in the var `MarkBack`, `tagName` is in quotes, not a variable?

Comment: Ok here is my code now but it still doesn't work. `var MarkBack = new RegExp("(\\b" + tagName + "\\b)", "gim");
  var MarkBackTo = "<mark class=" + Color + ">" + MarkBack + "</mark>"`     I am tying to reverse engineer my mark creator.

Comment: what is your `MarkBack` value.

Comment: It should be the word inside the mark tags (`tagName` is put into the javascript through an input bar)

Comment: @Hawkeye ya i understood that part, what I asked was for the value in it, I wanted you to debug the code and see what value is generated from that line of code.

Comment: the issue has been fixed. Thanks for all your help though. It was an issue with the regex not the javascript!

Comment: @Hawkeye But you said that it was working fine and started breaking after you added `class` to it, that is why we didn't look into the regex. Anyways glad it worked for you, Happy coding!!

Comment: Haha thanks! It was really weird because I thought I had tried the solution before!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know JavaScript very well, but I think it does not match because the class uses **""** to mark it's name, but you're slapping extra **''** in your regex.

Try

```
var MarkBackTo = "<mark class=" + ColorT + ">" + MarkBack + "</mark>"
```

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work. I do not know much about Regex so this is a difficult problem for me to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the way you build the RegExp is not right. Please try:

```
function removeMark(tagName, Color) {
  var tagNameC = tagName.toUpperCase();
  var IndAry = tags.indexOf(tagNameC);
  tags.splice(IndAry, 1);
  var Notes = document.getElementById("NoteHolder").innerHTML;
  var MarkBack = "(\\b + tagName + \\b)";
  var ColorT = '"' + Color + '"';
  var MarkBackTo = "<mark class='" + ColorT + "'>" + MarkBack + "</mark>"
  var AfterRep = Notes.replace(new RegExp(MarkBackTo, "gim"), "$1", );
  document.getElementById("NoteHolder").innerHTML = AfterRep;
  var list = document.getElementById("myList");
  var idmarker = "MarkID" + tagName;
  var ElementID = document.getElementById(idmarker);
  MarkList.removeChild(ElementID);
}
```